# MapKit blue dot not visible when using custom annotations

Tags: iphone, annotations, maps, mapkit

I am not able to see the Blue current location dot when I use custom annotations

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation> ) annotation {

    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ann.png"];
    [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];

    customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                                                                                                 
    //UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ann.png"]];
    //customAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return customAnnotationView;
}
```

Comment: You're not reusing your annotations, which becomes a significant memory waste if you have many of them and/or the user keeps panning around the map.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (annotation == map.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }
```

Add this.:d

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer now. Just need to add the following lines to the above code at the end just before **return customAnnotationView;**

> if (annotation ==
>   mapView.userLocation) {
>   NSLog(@"nil");    return nil; }

thanks :)

Comment: @user582835 If you're going to do it that way, don't put it down at the bottom, put it right at the top. You don't want to do all of that processing on an annotation that can't even use it. In addition you definitely don't need to log "nil".

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of the current user location "blue dot" is unrelated to custom annotations. To make the user's current location show, you need to set the `showsUserLocation` property of your `MKMapView` to `YES`. For example:

```
yourMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

or:

```
[yourMapView showsUserLocation] = YES;
```

Understand that there is a quirk in the way MapKit displays the current user location: in the simulator the UserLocation will *always* be Apple's headquarters in Cupertino, CA, USA. It will work fine on the device, however.

---

**Edited to add:**

As Terente points out, you do have to be careful not to "eat" the user's location annotation, and so must test to see if the annotation you're processing is the user's location. I wrap the logic with:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapLocation class]]) {

}
```

Where `MapLocation` is my annotation class.

Comment: I have done it. But I dont get the blue dot. I did as I stated in the posts below I am getting it now.   Thanks

Comment: +1 For mentioning that the simulator uses Cupertino as UserLocation... :)